# Jenkins connection closed after authentication succesful

Tags: linux, jenkins, jenkins-agent

Trying to configure linux agent node to my windows Jenkins controller, throwing below error after authentication is succesfull

```
SSH connection reports a garbage before a command execution.
Check your .bashrc, .profile, and so on to make sure it is quiet.
The received junk text is as follows:
/usr/bin/id: cannot find name for group ID ******

null
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the error it looks SSH is failing because the group doesn't exist in the destination Linux node.

Verify that the groups of the SSH user on the Jenkins Windows master using which SSH is happening to Linux node

[image]

Ensure that the SSH user exists on the Linux node and it is a member of the groups that appeared in Windows.

If there are any missing groups in Linux node as compare to Windows Master then you need to create them.

Do let me know the result for next step of troubleshooting.

Comment: I can able to login into linux node from my jenkins master

Comment: I was using account that is integrated with AD which has could load the all the profiles properly..Work around was to create a native account on Jenkins node and add public key there which made my life easy..

Comment: Yes, it's a good practice to use the local OS user for running the application process. User account from AD can impact application if application server lose connection with AD because of any reason